# Callbacks in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, oauth

Using the 'oauth2' gem and a Heroku server, I have managed to create a client object and redirect the user to the login site:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(
"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
:authorize_url => "/oauth/authorize",
:token_url => "/oauth/token",
:site => "https://connect.xxxxxxxxxx.com")

redirect_to(client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => 'https://xxxxx.herokuapp.com/callback'))
```

The browser afterwards redirects itself to the callback link as intended, something like:

```
https://xxxxx.herokuapp.com/callback?code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I need to access the authorization code to then send a post request for the access token and refresh token, but being totally new to Ruby and Ruby on Rails, I am not sure how to get the callback and parse the code out.  All of the dozen tutorials/documentation I've researched just mention that the authorization code should be 'magically obtained,' but I'm not sure how exactly that works explicitly.  I tried creating a 'callback' controller and view to no avail - is there something missing in the routes files possibly? Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your CallbackController will start to look like this maybe:

```
class CallbackController < ApplicationController
  def index
    access_token = client.auth_code.get_token(params[:code], redirect_uri: 'https://xxxxx.herokuapp.com/callback')
    # Now you have an OAuth2::AccessToken object that you can either use to:
    # - make direct requests to the API
    # - or access access_token.token, access_token.refresh_token, access_token.expires_at, access_token.expires_in and store those
    #   somewhere for later use
    # http://www.rubydoc.info/github/intridea/oauth2/OAuth2/AccessToken
  end

  private

  def client
    @client ||= OAuth2::Client.new(
      "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      authorize_url: "/oauth/authorize",
      token_url: "/oauth/token",
      site: "https://connect.xxxxxxxxxx.com"
    )
  end
end
```